# Ubuntu 18.04 / Dell Inspiron 15 7000 camera stopped working

Tags: dell, webcam

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 15 7000.

My webcam stopped to work have no idea why as it was perfectly fine last week, also it works on Windows flawlessly.

Some logs based on the stuff I searched already:

Cheese:

```
** Message: 15:28:53.833: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: Camera not found
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 27c6:5301  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6363 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1e7d:2dc2 ROCCAT 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

(0c45:6363 Microdia - this would be the webcam)

ls /dev/video*

```
Cannot access /dev/video*: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what could happened?